# Rewriting sbt artifacts with a regex matcher to strip version information

Tags: regex, scala, sbt

RegEx guru wanted: I want to strip library names in packaging an sbt project. Namely if my dependency is called

```
val in = "scala-swing-2.9.0-1.jar"
```

I want to re-write the name as

```
"scala-swing.jar"
```

E.g. given a method

```
def rewrite(p: util.matching.Regex, s: String) = s match {
  case p(name) => name + ".jar"
  case _       => s
}
```

I tried

```
rewrite("""([^-_]*)[-_].*.jar""".r, in)  // gives "scala.jar"
```

and

```
rewrite("""(.*)[-_]\d.*.jar""".r, in)    // gives "scala-swing-2.9.0.jar"
```

...

**EDIT:**

Bonus questions:

```
val in2 = "audiowidgets_2.9.0-1-0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar"
require(rewrite( ???, in2 ) == "audiowidgets.jar")

val in3 = "jsyntaxpane-0.9.5-b29.jar"
require(rewrite( ???, in3 ) == "jsyntaxpane.jar")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps get away with something simpler too:

```
"(.*?)[-_]\\d.*\\.jar".r
```

Comment: hmmm, yeah, that's seems to cover all cases. regex will always remain voodoo for me

Answer (score 2):

Finally I know what they are talking about with the 'greedy' and 'reluctant' attributions...

```
val re = """(.*?)(?:[-_](?:(?:[^-_]*\d)|SNAPSHOT))+.jar""".r

rewrite( re, in )  // "scala-swing.jar"
rewrite( re, in2 ) // "audiowidgets.jar"
rewrite( re, in3 ) // "jsyntaxpane.jar"
```